# Select items from a matrix or tensor using 1-D array of indexes to get 1D or 2D tensors in torch

Tags: python, pytorch, selection

I have a tensor of n-sampled predictions. In this example I sample 4 times a (10,2) result, where this results represents a batch of graphs with each graph having 3+4+3=10 nodes with 2 coordinates. I have a way to select the best sample for each graph, and I have an index telling me this (`idx_test`). I want to select in an efficient way the elements of the sampled tensor. The best way I have found is like this (toy code example):

```py
rand_test = torch.randint(3, 10, (4, 10, 2))
idx_test = torch.LongTensor([0, 3, 1])

n_nodes = [3, 4, 3]

final_tensor = torch.zeros((10, 2))
accum_nodes = torch.cumsum(torch.LongTensor(n_nodes), 0)
# First iteration is done outside the for loop
final_tensor[:accum_nodes[0]] = rand_test[idx_test[0],:accum_nodes[0],:]
for i, idx in enumerate(idx_test):
    final_tensor[accum_nodes[i-1]:accum_nodes[i]] = rand_test[idx,accum_nodes[i-1] :accum_nodes[i], :]
print(final_tensor)
```

The objective is to obtain the same final tensor without using for loops since in my model this array is large

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a helper tensor containing the ranges of node indices you want to index `rand_test` with. In your example, you have: `i=0` you have `3` nodes with index value `0`, `i=1` has `4` with value `3`, while `i=2` has `3` with index value `1`.

You can do so using [`repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html#torch.repeat_interleave):

```
>>> idx_test.repeat_interleave(torch.tensor(n_nodes))
tensor([0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1])
```

Then index `rand_test` using `idx` and a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

```
>>> final_tensor = rand_test[idx, range(len(idx))]
tensor([[5, 5],
        [7, 3],
        [8, 4],
        [7, 5],
        [7, 6],
        [7, 8],
        [9, 9],
        [7, 7],
        [8, 7],
        [3, 7]])
```